# Difference between run_wsgi_app and wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm just learning how to use python and GAE and I've noticed that the main URL handler is shown in two different ways. What's the difference in calling run_wsgi_app vs wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler? I've seen sample code shown in both manner.

```
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
      [
        ('/', MainPage),
        ('/sign', Guestbook)            
      ], debug = True)

  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

vs

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
      [
        ('/', MainPage),
        ('/sign', Guestbook)            
      ], debug = True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run_wsgi_app` is the one you should be using. Amongst other things, it runs any middleware defined in `appengine_config.py`. The `CGIHandler` approach dates from before `run_wsgi_app` was introduced. There shouldn't be any examples of this left in the docs - where did you find it?

Comment: The 'geochat' sample project from http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/

Comment: They are equivalent, except by what Nick pointed (they add middleware set in `appengine_config.py`). And it takes some shortcuts, because it knows exactly what to expect from the App Engine environment.